# Change Events to Tasks

Tags: tasks

I have a sales rep who in error starting creating Events instead of Tasks for things like calls since the beginning of the year. I've looked around and haven't been able to find anything on the Salesforce site indicating a way to change these events to tasks. The AppExchange seems to be offline.

Anyone have any ideas or experience with this? It is creating challenges with completed task reporting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can export those events onto a csv file using the salesforce data loader. Then edit those events records in an excel spreadsheet, and then import them back as task records. After that, delete the old event records.